# Memory Issues But memorytest is clean

Tags: memory, windows-8.1, motherboard, crash, hardware-failure

I got a 16GB system, and lately (I have made no hardware changes lately and no real software changes either) its been doing weird things with crashing and not letting me use all the memory.

SPECS:

- x64 FX8350 CPU AMD.
- x64 Win 8.1.
- 16GB DDR3.
- Geforce GTX 660 and GT 610 (for another screen)
- No onboard video card at all.
- NO hardware changes in months.

Symptoms: locks up if sits with no use for a couple of minutes. (not present anymore for some reason. Did a virus removal that found some stuff)

Still present issue:

TaskManager shows that I have 4 of 4 slots used with 4GB in each (CPU-Z agrees)
But also shows that Hardware resevered is 4GB giving me 12GB usable. Recently it suddenly just reset (windows shows no log of a crash) and hardware reserved jumped to 8GB giving me only 8GB. It crashed when I put my bare foot against the case. So I thought POSSIBLY a loose memory stick or something. So I pulled them out and put them back in. Shows 12GB availible, 4 being reserved.

Now I'm just waiting on it reset again and only give me 8. I ran a memory test, and no issue. Its **dual channel memory**, and again no changes for months.

Any ideas?

What I was thinking was one of the channels has a semi bad stick that when it fails, takes down the other stick on that channel causing windows to crash because suddenly it would be single channel memory instead of duel channel.

But...the memory test passed.

**HOWEVER...** the memory test skipped from 75-80% to complete.

Any ideas would be appreciated. I have no extra memory. Is this really a memory issue?

Btw I already shook the case so I think it was just a coincidence.

EDIT: To answer the question what I mean about not being able to use all the memory, I mean it reserves 4GB (hardware reserved) or after it crashed it reserved 8GB. In the screenshot below you can see it reserving 4 which means I cant use that.
Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Use Memtest86+ and run it for 48 hours (straight).

Comment: The fact memtestx86 is saying you have single channel isn't important provided it is scanning ALL your memory.  Its just a mode and a matter of available bandwidth.  You indicate you have no onboard GPU but don't indicate what GPU you do have.

Comment: im using windows memory test. Geforce GTX 660 and GT 610 (for another screen) Again no recent hardware changes @Ramhound

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 are you joking?

Comment: [Memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/) official download site, there are impostors that charge for this free software. No he is not joking, run it for 48 hours to stress test the memory modules.

Comment: Use memtest86 and test your ram in paurs: so slot 0 and 2 (take out ram from slots 1 and 3) and then the other way around. See if that brings you something.

Comment: @agtoever whats the idea of testing in pairs?

Comment: @JABFreeware - Update your question with the relevant information you forgot to share.

Comment: @JABFreeware - Process of elimination;  Reduces the possible variables;

Comment: @Ramhound did. Wasnt aware it was needed. Its not onboard.

Comment: No joke. If you suspect RAM due to intermittent problems, then a single memory scan using Window's tester isn't enough to test it thoroughly. Really though, what you're describing doesn't sound like a faulty RAM issue to me.  When you say things crash, is there any Event log entries that align with the crashes?  When you say it "won't let you use all the memory" what does that mean exactly?  Also if you had an infection that was causing problems, try a fresh Windows install and see if it behaves any better (damage may have been done that removing the infection didn't fix).

Comment: It takes as much time as running 4 banks but gives more info: if bank 0+2 fails, its either those slots OR those banks. You can then swaps banks and slots to determine if it's the bank or the slot. It's the principle of exclusion. Also: running 2x8 GB takes almost as much timeas running 1x16 GB so you lose nothing there.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 see edit for clarification, sorry abt that

Comment: @agtoever ahhh of course. I would have thought it would tell me which memory bank has the issue so I wouldn't have to do that. Besides I dont have 48hrs x 2 for the stresstesting.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 If it would be easier... here is a chatroom:   http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20060/memory-issues

Comment: Possible duplicates: [16GB of RAM installed, ~12GB useable](http://superuser.com/questions/583165/16gb-of-ram-installed-12gb-useable), [Why is all my extra RAM marked as “hardware reserved” in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/56157/why-is-all-my-extra-ram-marked-as-hardware-reserved-in-windows-7).  Go over the answers/comments on those and then come back and edit your question to include what you've tried and what the results were.

Comment: which motherboard do you use?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I would note that it still doesnt explain the change in reserved memory. I just triest 86memorytest and it only sees 12GB for some reason. My mobo does support the config

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution!

For reason... unknown to me, changing my slot layout helped. I have two GSKILL lines installed (they confirm that it wouldn't cause an issue)

I have always had them like this:

- Slot 1 (a chan): Type A

  Slot 2 (b chan): Type B

  Slot 3 (a chan): Type A

  Slot 4 (b chan): Type B

I read that that is good to keep one line on one channel...guess not. I changed it to:

- Slot 1 (a chan): Type A

  Slot 2 (b chan): Type B

  Slot 3 (a chan): Type B

  Slot 4 (b chan): Type A

And it work for some weird reason.

I'm thinking maybe a software update made the difference

For those of you having to wonder if windows is at fault or the hardware, USE MEMTEST86. At the start it tells you how much memory you have, and also is great at testing.

All 16GB is now usable.